# Can a pointer point to an address after 4GB?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory

If we compile and execute the code below:

```
int *p;
printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(p));
```

it seems that the size of a pointer to whatever the type is 4 bytes, which means 32 bit, so 2<sup>32</sup> adresses are possible to store in a pointer. Since every address is associated to 1 byte,  2<sup>32</sup> bytes give 4 GB.

So, how can a pointer point to the address after 4 GB of memory? And how can a program use more than 4 GB of memory?

Comment: The Windows x64 kernel and programs compiled natively for Windows x64 use 64 bit/8 byte pointers and can therefore use much more memory.

Comment: That's right, a 32-bit program can't. You'll have to compile as 64-bit, where the pointers are 64-bit.

Comment: In the old days, when pointers were 16-bit long, memory addressing was done by segmenting the memory and pointing into a place in a particular segment. Nowadays we just compile for 64-bit when we want greater range :P

Comment: @PavelAnossov He asks how a pointer can point to memory beyond 4GB. It can, even in a 32 bit processor because of paging and so forth.

Comment: @user3125280 When i said the adresse after 4GB I means the virtual memory not the physical.

Comment: @rullof In that case, it can't. Simple. There are ways to alter the virtual memory mapping of course, but that's tricky, so instead just get bigger virtual address space, right? :)

Comment: So 32 bit systems are not a good idea for any process that needs huge memory :)

Comment: What is your actual programming problem? This sounds like a CS question rather than a programming one.

Comment: @RaymondChen The problem that a non competent teacher was insesting that the pointer size is always 4 Bytes.

Comment: Don't print the result of `sizeof` with `%d`. Use `%zu` or convert the value to `int` before passing it to `printf("%d…`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By principle, if you can't represent an address which goes over `2^X-1` then you can't address more than `2^X` bytes of memory.

This is true for x86 even if some workarounds have been implemented and used (like [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension)) that allows to have more physical memory even if with limits imposed by the fact that these are more hacks than real solutions to the problem.

With a 64 bit architecture the standard size of a pointer is doubled, so you don't have to worry anymore.

Mind that, in any case, virtual memory translates addresses from the process space to the physical space so it's easy to see that a hardware could support more memory even if the maximum addressable memory from the process point of view is still limited by the size of a pointer.

Comment: PAE enables to OS to use more than ~4GB memory on 32 bit, however, no single process can use more than that.
On x86 64 bit, the pointer size is 48 bit.

Comment: @erenon "..that allows to have more physical memory..". I'm talking about physical memory indeed.

Comment: PAE is worth mentioning in this context, unfortunately it does not really answer the question. Interestingly, it is marked as the answer though.

Comment: This is of course all architecture dependent, so to be taken with a grain of salt. A 32 bits system can theoretically have as large a virtual memory space as it wanted. Just use a hierarchy of 32 bit pointers. There are other ways to "represent an address".

Comment: @JensG What was interesting for me is not PAE itsef but that there is way to solve the problem. what i understod from mapping is that when a pointer point to somewere it says to the following adresse in the following part of memory. I'm i right?

Comment: A pointer points to a contiguous block of memory with at least the allocated size. The physical memory is mapped into the available address space. Thus, physical adresses will very likely be not equal the addresses you see, because your pointer points into the address space for the application, not to physical memory. Any assumptions beyond that point should not be made, and rarely aren't necessary at all. Remember, the OS may move pages around and even swap memory contents temporarily out to disk, unless they are locked in memory.

Comment: @erenon 64 bit architecture's pointers are 64 bit as i checked in my Linux with 64 bit architecture

Comment: @rullof What erenon meant to say was that only 48 of the 64 bits of a pointer are effectively used currently.

Comment: @glglgl In this case he may be right. but for what the other bits?

Comment: @rullof They are reserved and must be zero. This is like seeing a cash register that has room for four digit prices and asking what the extra digit is for even though nothing in the store costs more than 999 Euros. It means that if the store ever adds something that costs 1000 Euros, it won't have to redesign their cash registers.

Answer (score 2):

To access >4GB of address space you can do one of the following:

- Compile in x86_64 (64 bit) on a 64 bit OS. This is the easiest.
- Use [AWE memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). AWE allows mapping a window of memory which (usually) resides above 4GB. The window address can be mapped and remapped again and again. Was used in large database applications and RAM drives in the 32 bit era.

Note that a memory address where the MSB is 1 is reserved for the kernel. Windows allows under several conditions to use up to 3GB (per process), the top 1GB is always for the kernel.

By default a 32 bit process has 2GB of user mode address space. It's possible to get 3GB via a special linker flag (in VS: /LARGEADDRESSAWARE).

Comment: AWE is correct, however somewhat picky. The user account under which the process runs needs the permission to Lock Pages in Memory - which is disabled by default with a very good reason. This makes it sometimes hard to put AWE programs onto production machines.

Comment: This is not a very clear answer - the pointer can point anywhere in memory because of virtual memory and paging. AWE memory just remaps the address space.

Comment: @user3125280 The question was: how can you use > 4GB of memory? With AWE you can do exactly that. You can't access it all at once, but that was not part of the question.

Comment: @JensG as you can see under the answer I thought the question was asking about physical memory after 4GB, not virtual. So anything that fiddles with the virtual mapping, such as AWE, is a relevant answer. Sorry

Comment: @egur The last 2 sentences contradict each other.

Comment: @glglgl: Added an explanation.

Comment: You don't need AWE to allocate and map memory. MapViewOfFile works just fine as long as you don't map more than 4GB at a time.

Answer (score 2):

"How can a pointer point to the address after 4GB of memory?"

There is a difference between the physical memory available to the processor and the "virtual memory" seen by the process. A 32 bit process (which has a pointer of size 4 bytes)  *is* limited to 4GB however the processor maintains a mapping (controlled by the OS) that lets each process have its own memory space, up to 4GB each.

That way 8GB of memory could be used on a 32 bit system, if there were two processes each using 4GB.

Comment: Actually, in a typical 32-bit OS design, only a fraction of 4GiB is available to one process. And by fraction I mean 1/2 or 3/4 (two typical values found in widespread OSes).